# How to set the athentication destails for Symfony DomCrawler?

Tags: php, phpunit, web-crawler, domcrawler

I am trying to crawl some web pages that need authentication, i.e. first you should login and then you can access the pages.

For that I am trying to use `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler` in my application (I am not using the Symfony Framework, I have used `symfony/dom-crawler` using Composer).

```
<?php
require_once('/vendor/autoload.php');
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class myTest extends WebTestCase {
    function __construct () {
        $crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents('http://test.com/index.php'));

        var_dump($crawler->filter('.menu_nav')->eq(0)->text());
    }
}

new myTest;
```

This is working perfectly fine for the simple pages, but not for authenticated ones, i.e. those that need username and password. So for that I am trying to use  [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html)  from Symfony website and insert this code:

```
<?php
require_once('/vendor/autoload.php');
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;    

class myTest extends WebTestCase {
    function __construct () {

        $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'username',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'pa$$word',
        ));

        // $crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents('http://test.com/index.php'));
        // var_dump($crawler->filter('.menu_nav')->eq(0)->text());
    }
}

new myTest;
```

But I am getting this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'You must override the KernelTestCase::createKernel() method.' in E:\xampp\htdocs\testCrawler\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php on line 44
```

To solve this I have added `phpunit.xml` at `path/to/my/project/phpunit.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="path/to/my/project" />
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./stats/Test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

From command prompt if I type `phpunit`, I get:

```
path/to.my/project>phpunit
PHPUnit 4.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from path/to.my/project\phpunit.xml

Time: 300 ms, Memory: 1.50Mb

No tests executed!

path/to.my/project>phpunit
```

That shows phpunit knows about the phpunit.xml file, but the error still exists.

**Update:** The purpose is not to use this program as a part of unit test or any other tests, this purpose is to crawl the pages, by any possible solutions.

Comment: initialise your component in the setup method

Comment: @Matteo Actually what I am trying to do, is to run this as the main program, not as the test.